# SQL - Fastest way to do an UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I've created a small program in PHP/MySQL to update a table in a database and I'm wondering how its performance would change introducing a condition in the UPDATE statement.

For now I'm executing the UPDATE on every record of the table, ignoring the fact that the field I'm going to update has been already calculated and updated:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE matches SET delta=".$delta." WHERE id=".$idp."");
```

where `$delta` is a PHP variable previously calculated and `id` is the unique key of the table.

Is there any difference in terms of speed of execution inserting a condition to determine if the delta field has already been calculated/updated in the table or if it's still set to 0 (its default value)?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE matches SET delta=".$delta." WHERE id=".$idp." and delta=0");
```

Is there any improvement adding the `delta=0` condition?

Summarizing my question: is the UPDATE faster when the write operation on the table is not executed because the `delta=0` condition is false? My table has about 10k records.

Thanks in advance and excuse my poor english! ;-)
Andrea

Comment: Depends on your data and indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing multiple updates like this then generally I would suggest doing an INSERT instead but with an on duplicate key condition to do the update when the id already exists. This way you potentially perform a single SQL query rather than one query for every record on the table.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO matches (id, delta)
VALUES
($idp1, $delta1),
($idp2, $delta2),
($idp3, $delta3),
($idp4, $delta4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE delta=VALUES(delta)
");
```

EDIT

This is a php class I sometimes use (mildly simplified version here) when doing mutliple inserts / updates

```
<?php

class table_process
{

    var $link;
    var $row_array = array();
    var $field_name_store = '';
    var $table_name = '';
    var $record_count = 0;
    var $update_clause = '';
    var $rows_to_process = 255;

    function __CONSTRUCT($link, $table_name, $update_clause = '')
    {
        $this->link = $link;
        $this->table_name = $table_name;
        $this->update_clause = $update_clause;
    }
    function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        if (count($this->row_array) > 0)
        {
            $this->process_rows();
        }
    }
    function field_names($in_field_names)
    {
        $this->field_name_store = "(`".implode("`,`", $in_field_names)."`)";
    }
    function record_count()
    {
        return count($this->record_count);
    }
    function make_row($in_row)
    {
        $ret = true;
        foreach($in_row AS &$in_field)
        {
            $in_field = (($in_field == null) ? "NULL" : "'".mysql_real_escape_string($in_field, $this->link)."'");
        }
        $this->record_count++;
        $this->row_array[] = "(".implode(",", $in_row).")";
        if (count($this->row_array) > $this->rows_to_process)
        {
            $ret =  $this->process_rows();
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    function process_rows()
    {
        $ret = true;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->table_name." ".$this->field_name_store." VALUES ".implode(",", $this->row_array)." ".$this->update_clause;
        if (!mysql_query($sql, $this->link))
        {
            $ret = false;
        }
        $this->row_array = array();
        return $ret;
    }
    public function set_rows_to_process($rows_to_process)
    {
        if (is_numeric($rows_to_process) and intval($rows_to_process) > 0)
        {
            $this->rows_to_process = $rows_to_process;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

You would then use this something like as follows:-

```
$ProcessMatches = new table_process($link, 'matches', ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE delta=VALUES(delta)', true);
$ProcessMatches->field_names(array('id', 'delta'));

$ProcessMatches ->make_row(array('id'=>$id1, 'delta'=>$delta1));
$ProcessMatches ->make_row(array('id'=>$id2, 'delta'=>$delta2));
$ProcessMatches ->make_row(array('id'=>$id3, 'delta'=>$delta3));
$ProcessMatches ->make_row(array('id'=>$id4, 'delta'=>$delta4));
$ProcessMatches ->make_row(array('id'=>$id5, 'delta'=>$delta5));
$ProcessMatches ->make_row(array('id'=>$id6, 'delta'=>$delta6));

unset($ProcessMatches);
```

The class takes a connection link and the table name / column names, along with an update clause (if required).

Each row you insert is taken by the class and built up for the insert. Once there are 255 rows ready to insert then it inserts them and wipes down the array storing them. Once you have finished, unset the object which triggers the __DESTRUCT method which does the final insert.

Comment: isn't an issue the fact that my $idp and $delta variables are 10.000+?

Comment: Possibly, but 10000+ separate update statements will be very time consuming. I tend to batch them up to around 250 at a time. I will update the answer with a bit of code I sometimes use.

Comment: Thank you @Kickstart; but still remains my last question: is the UPDATE faster when the write operation on the table is not executed because the delta=0 condition is false?

Comment: With updates not sure. It would force a check for each record. Potentially this could speed things up but I suspect it would depend on how many of the potential updates do result in an update. If you inserted all the updates to a temp table then did an update based on a join but checking that the value had changed as part of the join condition then the check probably would improve things. But this is all just my feeling of how things would work and I have not done any checking of it.